# Mysql to Json. Can this be solved using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have a MySQL query that will be converted to JSON and used in Obj C for each user with a specific id. I believe that this is a MySQL puzzle, but there may be an answer in JSON. I don't ask many questions, so I'll try to make it concise.

Here is a screen shot of values for one user. If you notice, the field_id may vary because not all info is required, so the id field will vary from 3 to 8 values for a given user_id:

[image: MySQL scenario screenshot]

I have to make a query where the results GROUP BY column1 (user_id), but only WHERE column2 (field_id) has the following values field_id='18' and field='19', Then (THE BIG PROBLEM) I need to populate the results in one GROUP with both values of column3 (value) so I can get results in one JSON object.

I already know how to convert to JSON for use in iOS, but I can only get it to give me results as two objects.

**My current query**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field_id='18' OR field_id='19' ORDER BY user_id ";
```

**Current Result**

```
[{"id":"5","user_id":"461","field_id":"18","value":"1_MX4zNjcxNzM5Mn4x...","access":"0"},

{"id":"6","user_id":"461","field_id":"19","value":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0...","access":"0"},

{"id":"11","user_id":"463","field_id":"18","value":"1_MX4zNjcxNzM...","access":"0"},

{"id":"12","user_id":"463","field_id":"19","value":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9...","access":"0"}]
```

I need the two JSON objects with matching user_id fields as one object with results that differentiate field='18' value from field='19' value. Something like:

```
    [{"id":"5","user_id":"461","field_id":"18","value18":"1_MX4zNjcxNzM5Mn4x...","value19":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0...","access":"0"},

{"id":"11","user_id":"463","field_id":"18","value18":"1_MX4zNjcxNzM...","value19":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9...","access":"0"}]
```

OR

```
    [{"id":"5","user_id":"461","field_id='18'":"1_MX4zNjcxNzM5Mn4x...","field='19'":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0...","access":"0"},

{"id":"11","user_id":"463","field_id='18'":"1_MX4zNjcxNzM...","field='19'":"T1==cGFydG5lcl9...","access":"0"}]
```

THANKS...

Comment: Check mysql group_concat  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: +1 for a well written question

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I tried using GROUP_CONCAT as Kay Nelson suggested below with slight promise. but as you see, the GROUP BY did not achieve the intended result of grouping the user_id field which is the main objective to create one object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this will work. I cannot easily try the JSON output of it. But what if you run a query like this?

```
SELECT id, user_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(field_id,':',value) field_id,
access
FROM table1 WHERE field_id='18' OR field_id='19' 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id
```

Comment: Slightly promising, the query did manage to GROUP_CONCAT the field_id and value for the user, but still left field_id 18 and 19 as seperate objects:                                                  {"id":"5","user_id":"461","field_id":"18:1_MX4zNjcxNz...","access":"0"},{"id":"6","user_id":"461","field_id":"19:T1==cGFydG5l...","access":"0"},

Comment: What if you try `GROUP BY user_id` only?

Comment: I tried that, it only responds with the first value and none of the others:    {"id":"1","user_id":"461","field_id":"2","value":"Male","access":"0"},{"id":"51","user_id":"462","field_id":"2","value":"Male","access":"0"}

Comment: THANKS A LOT @Kay Nelson , I just realized that I misunderstood you. I removed **id** from **GROUP BY id, user_id** to **GROUP BY user_id** and I finally got a result that should work when I figure out how to let iOS know that I want the values of field_id:18 and field:19. I'm hoping it's just as easy as adding the :18 or :19. HERE IT IS: `{"id":"5","user_id":"461","field_id":"18:1_MX4z...,19:T1==cG...","access":"0"}`

Comment: While `GROUP_CONCAT()` can certainly give you minimum capability to collapse different field records down to single user id. This also creates the problem of your client application needing to understand how to deal with the concatenated string values.  I would strongly suggest taking an approach whereby you structure the data more appropriately in PHP before encoding to JSON, such that the consuming client gets data in a more usable format.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to to look at handling this in PHP when reading in the result set.

So use your current query of

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field_id='18' OR field_id='19' ORDER BY user_id
```

But build result data object like this:

```
$results = array();
$i = -1;
$current_user_id = '';
while ($row = [YOUR MySQL FETCH MECHANISM HERE]) {
    // determine if this record represents a new user id in the result set
    // if so, we need to set up the user object and start another entry in top level array  
    if($current_user_id != $row['user_id']) {
        // you have moved to a new user in the result set
        // increment your array counter and set current user id
        $i++; // will set value to 0 on first iteration
        $current_user_id = $row['user_id'];
        // build new array entry
        $results[$i] = new stdClass();
        $results[$i]->user_id = $current_user_id;
        $results[$i]->fields = array(); 
    }
    // build field object for insertion
    $field = new stdClass();
    $field->field_id = $row['field_id'];
    $field->value = $row['value'];
    $results[$i]->fields[] = $field;
}
```

On encoding `$results` this would give you a JSON structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id":"461",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field_id":"18",
        "value":"foobar"
      },
      {
        "field_id":"19",
        "value":"abcxyz"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

This data structure is going to be more readily usable by consuming app than some solution which requires exploding concatenated field id/value strings. Also note that I have not included `id` field anywhere in data structure, as it has no meaning in this context. If you truly needed that id, you could add it as another property in the `field` object since that is where there is a one-to-one relationship (not with `user_id`).

Based on your comment, if the field value is known and you need to access it via field_id index, you can slightly modify what I have shown above to build index-able field listing rather than a simply array of objects:

```
$results = array();
$i = -1;
$current_user_id = '';
while ($row = [YOUR MySQL FETCH MECHANISM HERE]) {
    // determine if this record represents a new user id in the result set
    // if so, we need to set up the user object and start another entry in top level array  
    if($current_user_id != $row['user_id']) {
        // you have moved to a new user in the result set
        // increment your array counter and set current user id
        $i++; // will set value to 0 on first iteration
        $current_user_id = $row['user_id'];
        // build new array entry
        $results[$i] = new stdClass();
        $results[$i]->user_id = $current_user_id;
        $results[$i]->fields = array(); 
    }
    // insert field value at field_id index position
    $results[$i]->fields[$row['field_id']] = $row['value'];
}
```

This would give you a JSON representation like this.

```
[
  {
    "user_id":"461",
    "fields": {
        "18":"foobar",
        "19":"abcxyz"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

This would allow easy look-up by client based on field id.  Of course you may want to consider similar for user_id.  From the user object you could just access `fields->18` (or similar based on on client language syntax).

Comment: Thanks @mike currently my $results object is simple: `$rows = array();
while ($r =mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);' . The problem I see with this is that I still can't tell Obj C that I want the **value** of **field_id** **18** or **19** from the fields object...

Comment: @insitemobile OK. You can simply change the way you index the data.  You could have field be an object/associative array itself rather than an array of objects. See updated answer for simple change.  Bottom line is that you can easily structure the data you want in PHP before encoding, thus allowing the client application to work with the data more easily.